# Comparing to Generic type in xcode 10.2

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

Prior to the xcode 10.2 update (that includes swift 5 support) in following code both "a" and "b" would be "true", as intended. Now In xcode 10.2 with swift 4.2 in a previously created project "a" has started evaluating to "false".

If I change the project to swift 5, use an older version of xcode, or use the playground in xcode 10.2, "a" evaluates to "true" as intended.

As far as I can tell both "a" and "b" should never be different since `T` and `Any?` are the same thing in this case.

Why would this logic change and what could I do to achieve the same result?

```
class Class<T> {

    var val: String?

    func test(val: Any?) {
        let a = val is T
        let b = val is Any?
    }
}

let thing = Class<Any?>()
thing.test(val: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this one's my bad. To recap the history:

- In Swift 4.1, when casting from an optional value to a generic placeholder `T`, the compiler assumed that `T` was a non-optional type and so unwrapped the optional value before performing the cast. This means that `val is T` in your example would evaluate to `false`, as it would be evaluated as `val.map { $0 is T } ?? false` (not an actual AST transformation).
- Last year I opened a pull request ([#13910](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13910)) to fix this behaviour such that the compiler is now more conservative with the unwrapping, allowing `val is T` to evaluate to `true`.
- This fix made it into 4.2, however, due to not being guarded by `-swift-version 5`, caused a compatibility regression ([SR-8704](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8704)).
- To resolve the compatibility regression, for Swift 5 the fix was limited to Swift 5 mode only ([#19217](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/19217)) in order for the original behaviour to be preserved under Swift 4 and 4.2 compatibility modes. I was hoping we could also get this into 4.2.1 ([#19562](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/19562)) in order to minimise the flip-flopping in behaviour between 4.2 and 5.0, but unfortunately that didn't happen.

So long story short, in `-swift-version 4.2`, you're getting the original casting behaviour. To get the new behaviour, you can either use `-swift-version 5`, or erase the optionality of the source from the compiler, for example:

```
class Class<T> {

  var val: String?

  func test(val: Any?) {
    let a = (val as Any) is T
    let b = val is Any?
    print(a, b)
  }
}
```

or, with a dedicated function:

```
func valueIs<T, U>(_ x: T, ofType _: U.Type) -> Bool {
  return x is U
}

class Class<T> {

  var val: String?

  func test(val: Any?) {
    let a = valueIs(val, ofType: T.self)
    let b = val is Any?
    print(a, b)
  }
}
```